# How to show $charR=lcm\{a_1,...,a_m\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Suppose $R=\{a_1,...,a_m\}$ is a ring with order of $a_i=n_i$ for all $i\in\{1,...,m\}$ as a member of the additive group $R$. It is required to prove that $\operatorname{char}R=\operatorname{lcm}\{a_1,...,a_m\}$. (Here $\operatorname{char}R$ denotes the characteristic of $R$). My attempt is the following.

Say $\operatorname{lcm}\{a_1,...,a_m\}=l$. Then $n_i \mid l \ \forall i$. Therefore $a_i^l=0\ \forall i$, whence $\operatorname{char}R \mid l$. By division algorithm $\operatorname{char}R=kl+r$ where $0\leq r<l$. Thus $0=a_i^{\operatorname{char}R}=a_i^r\ \forall i$. Therefore $n_i \mid r\  \forall i$. Therefore $r=0$, whence $l \mid \operatorname{char}R$. Hence the result.

Is this proof alright? If not could someone please tell me what corrections I should use? Thanks.